# Coupon Code not working for configurable and bundle product type

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I have created Shopping Cart Price Rule and coupon code is XXXX. There are no any condition.

```
Action is: 
Apply: Percentage of product price discount 
Discount Amount: 10
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 1
Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0
Apply to Shipping Amount: no
Free Shipping: no
Stop Further Rules Processing: no
```

Above coupon code (XXXX) is working with simple product type but it is not working with configurable and bundle product type. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you applied condition to exclude any product type ?

Comment: @ArunKarnawat Thanks for your reply. I have already mentioned that there are no any condition.

Comment: try apply with conditions : `sku is` and mention configurable product sku....